# Jackson serializer for primitive types

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am writing a custom serializer to convert double values into strings in JSON objects. My code so far:

```
public String toJson(Object obj) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("DoubleSerializer", new Version(1, 0, 0, ""));

    module.addSerializer(Double.class, new DoubleSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
}

public class DoubleSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Double> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        String realString = new BigDecimal(value).toPlainString();
        jgen.writeString(realString);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine with Double (class members) but does not work for double (primitive type) members. For example,

```
    public void test() throws IOException {
        JsonMaker pr = new JsonMaker();
        TestClass cl = new TestClass();

        System.out.println(pr.toJson(cl));

    }

    class TestClass {
        public Double x;
        public double y;
        public TestClass() {
            x = y = 1111142143543543534645145325d;
        }
    }
```

Returns: {"x":"1111142143543543565865975808","y":1.1111421435435436E27}

Is there a way to make it follow same behavior for both cases?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can register the `JsonSerializer` for the primitive type `double`.

```
module.addSerializer(double.class, new DoubleSerializer());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with custom serializer, but there is a simpler way to.
Enable `JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS`:

```
mapper.getFactory().enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS);
```

Comment: I think this was added in v2.3. I am restricted to 2.2.

Comment: I've just tested it: you still get scientific notation

Comment: Actually this may well be true... since it just quotes numbers. And unfortunately while there is `JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN`, that only affects `BigDecimals` and not `double`s or `float`s. Might make sense to file an issue to add separate `JsonGenerator.Feature` for non-BigDecimal floating point values.